# Why does get_linesize() incorrectly return 1 for .fon fonts?

Tags: python-2.7, fonts, pygame

I've had this strange thing happen in Pygame1.9.1's font module, where `.get_linesize()` returns 1 for fonts whose glyph height (let alone per-line height) renders greater than 1. It only happens with `.fon` fonts.

Here are two examples, plus a third font that *does* work, for the sake of a control. I've run these from IDLE's shell, but the same thing happens with proper modules.
In any case, Pygame has already been initialized.

```
>>> testfont = pygame.font.Font("C:/Windows/Fonts/vga850.fon", 12)
>>> testfont.get_linesize()  # This one returns 1. For 'Terminal Regular'
1
>>> otherfont = pygame.font.Font("C:/Windows/Fonts/vgafix.fon", 18)
>>> otherfont.get_linesize() # This also returns 1. For 'Fixedsys Regular'
1
>>> lastfont = pygame.font.Font("C:/Windows/Fonts/OCRAStd.otf", 24)
>>> lastfont.get_linesize()  # This returns the correct value. For 'OCR A Std Regular'
29
>>> textsurf = testfont.render("This is a nightmare!", True, (0,0,0))
>>> textsurf.get_size()[1]   # Let's get the height of this surface...
12
>>> othersurf = otherfont.render("An inescapable nightmare!", False, (0,0,0))
>>> othersurf.get_size()[1]  # This one, too. Antialiasing makes no difference.
15
>>> lastsurf = lastfont.render("You're okay, OCRA.", True, (0,0,0))
>>> lastsurf.get_size()[1]   # And finally, the control...
25
```

The height of the render for the control is a little shorter, since `get_linesize()` includes a gap between lines for aesthetic reasons.
`<Font>.size("sample string")[1]` works correctly, so that's been my stopgap for line height.

All three fonts render correctly.

The common thread with the fonts that do not respond properly to `<Font>.get_linesize()` is that they all share the extension `.fon`, so the easy 'solution' is simply, "Do not use `.get_linesize()` with *.fon* fonts; use `.size('sample')[1] + some_adjustment` instead."
This, however, is somewhat inelegant and (worse still!) terribly boring, and I'm much more interested to know **what causes this problem,** and if there is **a way to make these fonts work with `get_linesize()` as they should.**

I looked through Pygame's documentation and couldn't find anything to do with this issue, and a number of web searches proved fruitless as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pygame's `Font` support depends on [SDL_ttf](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/) which in turn depends on [freetype2](http://www.freetype.org). I suspect there's some problem in calculating the value for line height as the font goes through those layers (specifically the SDL_ttf layer, as freetype2 just reads the font data).

Consider using [pygame.freetype.Font](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html) instead of pygame.Font. The freetype module skips the SDL_ttf layer and works with freetype directly. There is [a much richer](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font) set of options for fonts there. I'd try [get_sized_height()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.get_sized_height) as a replacement for get_linesize().

If that still doesn't work, most likely it is a freetype bug in reading FON files, or possibly the FON files themselves don't have the value set correctly.

Comment: I tried going over to freetype, actually, but I'm still using Python1.9.1. When I first considered the module, the doc said that it was still experimental and could change unpredictably or vanish all together, so I got cold feet and left it alone.
Looks like times changed (in the past month), though, and also I need to update.